# Express server not working with the ionic frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ionic-framework, postman

I am trying to send HTTP POST request from the frontend to the backend. I first tried the backend with postman and it worked fine. However, when I tried it with the frontend it did not respond. There are no errors or warnings, it just does not post anything to the database and does not return a response. Here is my HTTP request from the frontend:

```
 public addReg(UserOb) {
    console.log("callingaddReg");
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("content-type", "application/json");
    console.log("headers appended");
    return this.http
      .post("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register", UserOb)
      .map(res => {
        return res;
      });
  }
```

The above method logs `headers appended` in the console. 
The backend method which handles the request is as follows:

```
router.post("/auth/register", isNotAuthenticated, authCtrl.register);
```

Here is the isNotAuthenticated middleware:

```
var isNotAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
    // Check that the request doesn't have the JWT in the authorization header
    var token = req.headers["authorization"];
    if (token) {
        return res.status(403).json({
            error: null,
            msg: "You are already logged in.",
            data: null
        });
    }
    next();
};
```

The end point location is in the `index.js` file

- api

  - routes

    - index.js

Here is the URL to my monogdb:  `'mongodb://localhost:27017/waterProject'`